# Query of two filtered ranges doesn't display any results, if one filtered range has no matches

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to query two filtered ranges to get the combined average:

```
=QUERY({FILTER(Filtered Range #1);FILTER(Filtered Range #2)},  
"select avg(Col2)    
label avg(Col2)' ' ", 0)
```

This query works great, EXCEPT when either of these filtered ranges happens to not have any matches, in which case the whole query will return as #VALUE! without even querying the other range's matches.

Is there any way to get around this? I've tried incorporating `IFERROR` statements in various places. I've tried averaging two separate queries, but taking the average of two averages isn't ideal.

Here's my [Example Worksheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b29gyEgCDwor_KJ6ACP2rxdvauOzacDI9FL2K-jgg5E/edit#gid=1652431688).

Please see how since there are no matches for the `FILTER` Condition 1 in the 2018 sheet, the whole `QUERY` does not return, even though there are matches in the 2019 sheet.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Enclose `FILTER(...)` in `IFNA(FILTER(...), SPLIT(REPT(",", N), ",", True, False))`, where `N` is the number of columns `FILTER` should return.

This `SPLIT` will give you a dummy `{"", "", ..., ""}` - N columns of empty cells which could be easily ignored in `QUERY`.

It will look something like:

```
=QUERY(
  {
    IFNA(FILTER(Filtered Range #1), SPLIT(REPT(",", 2), ",", True, False));
    IFNA(FILTER(Filtered Range #2), SPLIT(REPT(",", 2), ",", True, False))
  },
  "select avg(Col2)
   where Col1 is not null
   label avg(Col2) ''",
  0
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't see the SPLIT in the formula you entered into the example sheet, but it works anyway and I adapted it for the average query which is great! When I go to replace the "2019" and "2020" sheet references with INDIRECT references and adapt my query a little to query values from within the last 12 months only, it doesn't seem to return. I wonder if there's something wrong with my query?

Comment: @Leanna In the example I entered `{"", ""}` manually, Using `SPLIT` is a more general solution - gives you the row of empty values of the right size calculated on the spot. That row is needed for the resulting range, with which `QUERY` will work, to be consistent.

Comment: @Leanna for some reason this part of the query does not work as expected: `and Col1>= date '" & TEXT(NOW()-365, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "'`. Everything else works fine.

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks for the explanation. This query `Col1 >= date '" & TEXT(NOW()-365, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "'` works fine in my original formula (see the "Example Matrix" tab) so I'll dig into it a little more.